# ThreeJS Equidistant Sphere Points

Tags: three.js

How can I generate an equidistant points in sphere? I want to know if there are faster ways to do this in `ThreeJS`.

The sphere on the left is what I want to achieve.
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hKs.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var spherePoints = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,16,16).vertices;
```

spherePoints will be an array of THREE.Vector3() points of radius 1 with 16 rows, and 32 ribs, or something close to that.

Comment: Thanks! This is honestly the first step to do that.